# Vuejs Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs2

So i have a vuejs project that i am working on and i had to do a reinstall of the npm node module so i ran NPM INSTALL. After running the command and trying to start the development server it showed me a lot of errors. I tried deleted node_modules and package.json.lock and ran again NPM INSTALL but same errors came up. How can i solve this please? Thanks in advance! These are the errors.

````
  "exclude": [
    null
  ],
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js",
      "options": {
        "cacheDirectory": "/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/.cache/babel-loader",
        "cacheIdentifier": "3763ed20"
      },
      "ident": "clonedRuleSet-38[0].rules[0].use[0]"
    },
    {
      "loader": "/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js",
      "options": "undefined",
      "ident": "undefined"
    }
  ]
}
Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude) in {
  "exclude": [
    null
  ],
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js",
      "options": {
        "cacheDirectory": "/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/.cache/babel-loader",
        "cacheIdentifier": "3763ed20"
      },
      "ident": "clonedRuleSet-38[0].rules[0].use[0]"
    },
    {
      "loader": "/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js",
      "options": "undefined",
      "ident": "undefined"
    }
  ]
}
    at checkResourceSource (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuleSet.js:167:11)
    at Function.normalizeRule (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuleSet.js:198:4)
    at rules.map (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuleSet.js:110:20)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeRules (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuleSet.js:109:17)
    at new RuleSet (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuleSet.js:104:24)
    at new NormalModuleFactory (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:115:18)
    at Compiler.createNormalModuleFactory (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:636:31)
    at Compiler.newCompilationParams (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:653:30)
    at Compiler.compile (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:661:23)
    at compiler.hooks.watchRun.callAsync.err (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:77:18)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Watching._go (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:41:32)
    at Watching.compiler.readRecords.err (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:33:9)
    at Compiler.readRecords (/Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:529:11)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c vue-cli-service serve

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2020-11-25T22_35_03_818Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: Maybe try to reinstall Vue CLI

Comment: @Chez any luck?

Comment: @Grandizer - yes, i actually solved this problem. I found it right here: https://blog.meathill.com/fe-tool-chain/how-to-fix-error-rule-can-only-have-one-resource-source-provided-resource-and-test-include-exclude.html

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when I was trying to include sass in my project and this worked for me:

```
npm install -D sass-loader node-sass
```